# Changing database table based on one column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, dynamic, mariadb

I am new to database design, but not to computers and terminology. I need some help in my database design. I am collecting data from a Global Navigation Satellite System (GNSS) receiver and each packet is differing in sizes depending on which constellation it sees (GPS, GALILEO, GLONASS, etc). There are some common fields across them all, but the way I currently have it set up is all the possible fields are columns, and any field that is unrelated to the new packet is just NULL. This is very inefficient, I just don't know how to go about designing a better way. Thoughts? The main point is as it is now, every time I do a query, I either specify all the fields that are relevant to that specific packet type, or I get a bunch of useless data.

I was thinking of one option, where I have all the common fields in one table, and another table for the unique fields for each packet type. Then have a column that tells what type of packet it is, so when I do a SELECT query I can do a JOIN and only get the data that is relevant to said packet.

Comment: With fields, do you mean telemetric data? that is, measures? One satellite can have thousands of different telemetric measures, that wouild mean thousands of columns of the type FLOAT sometimes luckily INTEGER or BOOLEAN. Is this what we are talking about?

Comment: Yes and no, but we are not worrying about the Almanac data as that is not important to us. We are looking more at the measurements that the NovAtel is returning, so no need to store all the Keplarian orbital parameters. There are a couple of commands we intend to have the receiver send back and it is that data, that will be stored. We are not storing 1000's of  columns, more like ~100. There will be 1000's of entries over time but not number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Thousands of rows of a hundred columns, many of which are NULL?  Sounds fine.

It might help if you provided a `CREATE TABLE`; there could be tips on datatypes, etc.

It is usually a good idea to "cleanse" data that comes in from external sources.  Especially if, say, two consellations provide the same value in a different format.  In this example, have one column and convert one (or both) from the given format to the table's datatype.  Sometimes that is 'automatic'.  For example, for a `FLOAT` or `DECIMAL(6,3)` column, "123.456" and "1.23456e2" look different, but go into `FLOAT` the same.  (OK, there could be a rounding difference.)  You may choose to use `DOUBLE`.

`NULLs` don't cost much.  Perhaps the main concern is *your* programming effort.

Your title "changing database based on column" -- that is messy; don't do it.